# Assign mutable reference to immutable reference

Tags: rust

This code doesn't compile. But it fails on the last line marked `Err`, not the line marked `Ok`. Why can we assign a mutable reference to an immutable reference type but not use it after the assignment?

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 10;
    let mut y = 20;
    let mut r = &x;
    r = &mut y; //Ok
    *r = 30;    //Err
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why can we ... not use it after the assignment?

The variable `r` is an immutable reference of type `&i32`; it does not have mutable access to the referenced value. So it makes sense the compiler would reject your attempt to assign through it.

> Why can we assign a mutable reference to an immutable reference type ...?

Why wouldn't you be able to downgrade a mutable reference into an immutable one? The latter is a strict subset of the former. If you were asking about the technicalities instead of the practicalities, its because `&mut T` to `&T` is a supported [coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-types).

Answer (score 1):

If we add explicit types to your code as inferred by the compiler:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x: i32 = 10;
    let mut y: i32 = 20;
    let mut r: &i32 = &x;
    r = &mut y; //Ok
    *r = 30;    //Err
}
```

We see that `r` has type `&i32` and not `&mut i32`, so of course we can't use `r` to modify the referenced value.

Why can we still do `r = &mut y`? Simply because we can always use a `&mut` reference anywhere a `&` reference is expected (because [`&mut T` implements `Deref<Target=T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#impl-Deref-6), allowing [coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-types) to happen).

Comment: Not `Deref` is what allows the coercion, [it is a special case in the compiler](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/7feb003882ecf7699e6705b537673e20985accff/compiler/rustc_hir_typeck/src/coercion.rs#L325).