# How to REALLY PROPERLY convert mutable reference to immutable reference in Rust?

Tags: rust, reference, borrow-checker, ownership

I've searched about this question before, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366896/how-to-make-a-rust-mutable-reference-immutable) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74176572/assign-mutable-reference-to-immutable-reference), but following the solution of the first link and try to apply them to my code, rustc seems misunderstand what I'm trying to do.

I wanted to create a linked list and assign some reference to the middle of the nodes and print their values. First I made them mutable in order to create the list from head ref to tail ref, then I wanted to convert them to be immutable, from tail ref to head ref, which wouldn't violate ownership rules. In the end, I wanted to access some immutable references(midway points) to get their values.

My code: ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a98313e015b4ddcf2be2428fe2e1389f))

```
struct Node<T> {
    val: T,
    next: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}
impl<T> Node<T> {
    fn new(val: T) -> Option<Box<Node<T>>> {
        Some(Box::new(Node { val, next: None }))
    }
}
fn main() {
    let head = &mut Node::new(0);
    let a = &mut head.as_mut().unwrap().next;
    *a = Node::new(10);
    let b = &mut a.as_mut().unwrap().next;
    *b = Node::new(20);
    let c = &mut b.as_mut().unwrap().next;
    *c = Node::new(30);
    let tail = &mut c.as_mut().unwrap().next;
    *tail = Node::new(40);
    // Trying to make these mutable reference immutable.
    let tail = &*tail;
    // reference 'c' is converted to immutable,
    // so nothing borrows 'b' as mutable anymore
    let c = &*c;
    // Reports error anyway.
    // error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*b` as immutable
    // because it is also borrowed as mutable
    //  16 |     let c = &mut b.as_mut().unwrap().next;
    //     |                  ---------- mutable borrow occurs here
    // Didn't I just convert c to immutable?
    let b = &*b;
    let a = &*a;
    let head = &*head;
    println!(
        "a is {}, b is {}, c is {}",
        a.as_ref().unwrap().val,
        b.as_ref().unwrap().val,
        c.as_ref().unwrap().val
    );
}
```

Things had gone wrong here, rustc still reports that I try to borrow them as immutable because they are borrowed by ref that is mutable. But I already converted the ref to immutable before. Why?

Could there be any solution to make my program run as expected?

Comment: A playground link is good but not enough; the question must be self-contained.

Comment: I think you're trying to force a pointer-style approach onto Rust here, which it doesn't really like or make easy. Why can't you have an `append()` method that adds on a `Box<Node<T>>`?

Comment: A reborrow that ends the original lifetime of the `&mut` and starts a new with `&` would allow for undefined behavior. See [this](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md#9-downgrading-mut-refs-to-shared-refs-is-safe)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot.

You can convert a mutable reference to immutable one, as the linked questions show, but the object will still be borrowed mutably.

This is necessary for APIs like [`Cell::from_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.Cell.html#method.from_mut) to be sound: they convert a mutable reference to immutable, and rely on the object to continue be mutably borrowed.

If you want, you can re-follow the `next` pointers immutably:

```rust
let head = &*head;
let a = &head.as_ref().unwrap().next;
let b = &a.as_ref().unwrap().next;
let c = &b.as_ref().unwrap().next;
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=80f95d10de1ccd5093abcb5eab702ced).

But really, this whole linked-list-style-programming doesn't really fit into Rust.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that a node owns its successors, so

- `c` owns `tail`
- `b` owns `c` and `tail`
- `a` owns `b`, `c` and `tail`
- `head` recursively owns the entire linked list.

This means that you can't keep a reference to `head` while mutating nodes it points to.

It doesn't matter if `head` is mutable or not; Rust's borrowing rules require that when you have a mutable reference to something, there can't be any other reference to the same data, mutable or not. A mutable reference is guaranteed to be *exclusive*.

You can fix your code by not keeping the references around:

```rs
let head = ...;
let a = &mut head.as_mut().unwrap().next;
drop(head);
```

The `drop(head)` isn't actually needed thanks to non-lexical lifetimes. A reference is implicitly invalidated **when used for the last time**.

So this code works:

```rs
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node<T> {
    val: T,
    next: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

impl<T> Node<T> {
    fn new(val: T) -> Option<Box<Node<T>>> {
        Some(Box::new(Node { val, next: None }))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let head = &mut Node::new(0);

    let a = &mut head.as_mut().unwrap().next;
    *a = Node::new(10);

    let b = &mut a.as_mut().unwrap().next;
    *b = Node::new(20);

    let c = &mut b.as_mut().unwrap().next;
    *c = Node::new(30);

    let tail = &mut c.as_mut().unwrap().next;
    *tail = Node::new(40);

    println!("head is {head:?}");
}
```

Note that you aren't able to access `a`, `b` and `c` at the end. However, you can still print them by accessing `head`.

You can also add a custom `Debug` implementation to get prettier output:

```rs
use std::fmt;

impl<T: fmt::Debug> fmt::Debug for Node<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        let mut node = Some(self);
        write!(f, "[")?;
        while let Some(next_node) = node {
            write!(f, "{:?}, ", next_node.val)?;
            node = next_node.next.as_deref();
        }
        write!(f, "]")
    }
}
```

Then the output looks like this:

```
head is Some([0, 10, 20, 30, 40, ])
```

Note that there is an easier way to construct a linked list by creating the nodes in reverse order:

```rs
struct Node<T> {
    val: T,
    next: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

impl<T> Node<T> {
    fn tail(val: T) -> Self {
        Node { val, next: None }
    }

    fn add(self, val: T) -> Self {
        Node { val, next: Some(Box::new(self)) }
    }
}

let head = Node::tail(40)
    .add(30)
    .add(20)
    .add(10)
    .add(0);
println!("head is {head:?}");
// output:
// head is [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, ]
```

[Full code in playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9dc67bc0fe86dc9d670e6d62c1bd9479)

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Feel free to edit it to make it more clear. English is not my native language, I don't find the best way to convey what I mean.

Comment: The problem is I'm not sure what you meant.

Comment: @Aloso, I think you’re good here. I thought your wording was clear.

Comment: I mean that you can't have two references to something when one of them is mutable, and then the mutability of the other reference doesn't matter.